# How can I inspect $element variable in theme function?

Tags: theming, debugging

I would like to change formatter of [Field Collection Table](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection_table), so that class added to a table row corresponds to a value of field of field collection item. As a first step, I would like to inspect theme function of that module. However, if I modify it to:

```
function theme_field_collection_table_multiple_value_field($variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $header = array();
  $cells = array();

  // Order field widgets by their widget weight.
  $instances = field_info_instances($element['#entity_type'], $element['#bundle']);
  uasort($instances, '_field_collection_table_sort_items_widget_helper');
  foreach ($instances as $field_name => $instance) {
    if (empty($element[$field_name])) {
      continue;
    }

    $header[] = _field_collection_table_get_title($element[$field_name]);
    $cells[] = array('data' => $element[$field_name]);

    // Remove the original field to prevent duplicate printing.
    unset($element[$field_name]);
  }

  $element['field_collection_table'] = array(
    '#theme' => 'table',
    '#header' => $header,
    '#rows' => array($cells),
    '#weight' => 0,
  );

  $element['#sorted'] = FALSE;
  dpm($element);
  return drupal_render_children($element);
}
```

no krumo element is displayed. I cleared both opcache and drupal cache several times, but the problem persists. Also, I did deliberate error to make sure, that theme function applies. Do you know, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If `dpm($element)` isn't returning output at that stage, you can log the data instead (temporarily) to the watchdog log.

e.g:

```
watchdog('dev', '<pre>' . var_export($element, 1) .'</pre>');
```

You can then view it at *Admin > Reports > Recent log entries*

Comment: Thanks, I tried it. But again, there is no output. Perhaps I have a completely wrong approach, or expectations: I'm using Field Collection Table formatter for a field, entity is displayed using specific view mode by Views and the view content pane is displayed using Panels. Maybe I should try with fewer levels of abstraction?

Comment: If there's no output it's pretty likely the theme function isn't running @MilošKroulík. You can test definitively by adding `die();` in there. If you still see the site, you know what's wrong

Comment: Thanks @Clive, I already made a deliberate error so I'm sure the theme function applies. I will update the answer.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should initialize the $element variable as a array element before this part of code..

```
   **$element = array();**
     $element['field_collection_table'] = array(
        '#theme' => 'table',
        '#header' => $header,
        '#rows' => array($cells),
        '#weight' => 0,
```

);

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. You're suggesting I should change the module code (the code above is copied directly from the module, except my `dpm` call) to make this work? That shouldn't be necessary, I think.

Comment: For good or bad, PHP doesn't require that you initialise arrays before accessing them as such, so this wouldn't make any difference, even if we ignore the fact that `$variables['element']` is already an array

Comment: but you are unset the a $element that's why i thought and just for more specific coding standard  I told you.